# Default encoding conflictions between R, VS Code and Windows

Tags: r, windows, visual-studio-code, encoding, utf-8

I'm having issues regarding conflicting encoding between R, VS Code and Windows 10 itself.

I use two different computers to work with big `.R` files.

Sometimes my files open blank in R;
Sometimes when I save them full of texts, they simply become a 0 Kb and blank as if I saved them empty.
Sometimes, when I open the file in VS Code, they appear with conflicted characters (á, ã, ç etc.).

1. I tried to set all my systems, Rstudio's and VSCode's to one unique default encoding.

R Studio:

```
Tools > Global Options > Saving > Default text encoding > ISO-8859-1
```

VS Code:

```
Preferences > Settings > Files: Encoding: Western (ISO 8895-1)
Preferences > Settings > Extensions > R > Source: Encoding: iso-8895-1
```

Windows 10:

```
PS C:\d> [System.Text.Encoding]::Default

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Europa Ocidental (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252
```

2. Then, within VS Code, I managed to write a new code and saved it as `d04.R`. Encoding `ISO 8859-1`.
3. Then I tried to open it from RStudio - it was shown as empty.
4. Then I went `File > Reopen with encoding... > Choose encoding` and two things happened:

a. First, it stated that my System Default was `UTF-8`.
b. Second, when I change the file to be reopened as `UTF-8`, it shows the text normally.

This is **confusing**, and I don't know more what I can do to guarantee I won't lose more weeks of work because of these incompatibilities.

BTW, as I am writing this on my regular Notepad, the encoding is also set as `UTF-8`.

How can I set the same default to all these programs?

Thanks!

Some screenshots to show you what's happening:

**Windows PowerShell:**

[image: Windows PowerShell]

**R Studio Global Options:**

[image: R Studio Global Options]

**VS Code Preferences:**

[image: VS Code Preferences]

**R code wrote in VS Code with `ISO 8895-1`:**

[image: R code wrote in VS Code with ISO 8895-1)]

**Same file being opened in R Studio:**

[image: Same file being opened in R Studio]

**R Studio Reopen with Encoding option:**

[image: R Studio Reopen with Encoding option]

**Changing to `UTF-8`, text becomes visible with `?` in place of some characters:**

[image: Changing to UTF-8, text becomes visible with ? in place of some characters]

Comment: We are in 3rd Millennium: switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: The blank files is most likely due to you working of a network drive.

Comment: I tested with `.R` files in the drive root of my main computer (E:\) before writing this question. 
Both programs as well ( `E:\Rapps\Microsoft VS Code`; `E:\Rapps\R\RStudio` ). I set up this way in my notebook.
I'm afraid it stared because of some misconfig that now is ruining the compatibility. That's why I wanted to set up the same default encoding, but it still opened blank files.

Comment: @JosefZ, I am trying to set up one encoding to rule them all in my devices. But it's hard for me: I'm no professional programmer beyond computing statistics.

Comment: It should not be hard per se to use Latin-1 or the near-equivalent Windows-1252 if you desperately want to; but you should understand that this restricts you to a very limited repertoire of 256 characters (or slightly less actually, as most of the control range serves no useful purpose for displaying text). Windows unfortunately makes it a bit hard to accommodate UTF-8 everywhere; if Windows is not central to your use case, getting rid of it can be quite liberating, and improve your experience (but there will be some learning curve if you have spent your life in the Microsoft Roach Motel).

Comment: How to make this conversion to UTF-8 everywhere? I tried to make Windows, R Studio and VS Code from two different PCs to stay in the same encoding, and it didn't work. That's my question there.